# Neatly open cereal box

Tags: storage

I figured out this a while ago and wanted to share it.

When you open a box (of cereal), you risk tearing the flap or cutting your finger on the cardboard. Or, at least, I do.

How can I open the box more neatly/easily?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I'm opening a new box of cereal, I have a spoon in my hand/nearby already.

1. Turn the spoon around so that the handle is sticking out.
2. Place the handle between the top flaps of the box (you may have to start in
   the middle, where there is less glue).
3. Slide the handle "blade" down
   the length of the flap, dislodging the glue on both sides.
4. Open the box easily.

Hopefully, this helps someone. :-)

Comment: I always use the butter knife, which isn't sharp and is rounded at the tip...

Comment: @Bamboo The handle of my spoons are rounded at the tip, but I could see how they wouldn't be. <jovial tone> Also, you already have the spoon out. Nobody got time to be taking out all kinds of utensils to open cereal </jovial tone>

Comment: Heh heh, butter knife's always out in my house; But maybe you've got less seconds to spare than me;-)) Whatever works best, anyway...

Comment: I always use this technique too! Still trying to convert my wife.

Comment: I just tear the box, since I usually put all my cereals in hermetic containers :3